# How to build a rule: assignableTo metaannotated?

Tags: java, archunit

I want to find all classes that are `metaAnnotated` or are `assignableTo` `metaannotated` with any version of `Immutable` annotation.

That is all classes metaAnnotated as immutable or implementing / extending anything that's metaAnnotated as immutable.

I tried:

```
DescribedPredicate m = simpleNameEndingWith("Immutable");
DescribedPredicate a = CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.metaAnnotatedWith(m);

System.out.println(productionClasses.that(a));
```

but it throws runtime exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaAnnotation cannot be cast to class com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass (com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaAnnotation and com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClass are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

How can I find all those classes?

Sample structure

```
class A extends B {}
class B implements C {}

@AnnotationD
interface C {}

@Immutable
@interface AnnotationD {}
```

I want to find class A and B because they are assignable to classes meta-annotated with @Immutable.

Comment: Can you include an example of such a class in your question?

Comment: @knittl done, i added class structure

Comment: Did the provided answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@ArchTest
final static ArchRule rule = ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
        .that().areMetaAnnotatedWith(Immutable.class)
        .or().areAssignableTo(CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.metaAnnotatedWith(Immutable.class))
        .should(...)
```

It applies the rule to all classes that are meta-annnotated with `@Immutable` or that extend/implement a class/interface that itself is annotameta-annotated with `@Immutable`.

If you require more flexibility, you can also define your own predicates to select the relevant classes, e.g.:

```
@ArchTest
static ArchRule rule = ArchRuleDefinition.classes()
        .that().areMetaAnnotatedWith(nameEndsWith("Immutable"))
        .or().areAssignableTo(CanBeAnnotated.Predicates.metaAnnotatedWith(nameEndsWith("Immutable")))
        .should(...);

private static DescribedPredicate<JavaAnnotation<?>> nameEndsWith(final String suffix) {
    return DescribedPredicate.describe(
            "annotation name ending with " + suffix,
            javaAnnotation -> javaAnnotation.getRawType().getSimpleName().endsWith(suffix));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that worked for me

```
final DescribedPredicate<HasType> immutable =
                rawType(simpleNameEndingWith("Immutable")); // string due to multiple annotation providers

fields().that()
     .areDeclaredInClassesThat().areMetaAnnotatedWith(immutable) 
     .or().areDeclaredInClassesThat()
                 .implement(INTERFACES.and(metaAnnotatedWith(immutable)))
```